# Can't write to Firestore Emulator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

i'm using Firebase and React. I'm not able to write to my emulator data, or rather, i can't see it after writing. So when a user signs up, i copy their name to Firestore, so even though the web app gives appropriate notifications, nothing has been added to `http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore`.
I want to create an emulator for functions, firestore, hosting, auth and storage but only auth is working. I can sign up users and view them on `http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth`.

I can even edit the data from the website but i don't know where or if the data is on my emulator. I know that its not on my production site though.

firebase.js:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
};

const hostname = window.location.hostname;
const app =
  hostname === "localhost"
    ? initializeApp({
        apiKey: "demo-key",
        authDomain: "demo-test",
        projectId: "demo-test",
        storageBucket: "default-bucket",
        appId: "demo-appId",
      })
    : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

if (hostname === "localhost") {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099,
      "host": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001,
      "host": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080,
      "host": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000,
      "host": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199,
      "host": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 4000,
      "host": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

Just to be clear, it doesn't make a difference whether i make use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in `firebase.json` or `firebase.js`

An image of user being signed up and the database that firebase is writing to, which i don't know how to access:
[image: user credentials and database information]

Please help, i would really appreciate your assistance. I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from my comments:

In order to match the emulator project ID with the project ID in the application, start the emulators with the following:

`firebase emulators:start --project=demo-test` where `demo-test` is the project ID in your `initializeApp` configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` can resolve to a different loopback address depending on your system (IPv4 vs IPv6)

```
ping localhost -c 1
PING localhost(localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
```

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -c 1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

What looks to be happening here is that your emulators are running on 127.0.0.1 but you're attempting to connect to `localhost` via `connectFirestoreEmulator`.

The fix is to use an explicit IP address there too:

`connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "127.0.0.1", 8080);`

The emulator suite doesn't support listening on IPv6 addresses yet.

Edit: Also update the `hostname === "localhost"` checks since they will no longer resolve `true` when connecting to `127.0.0.1` in your browser.

Comment: I have just made the changes you advised, ```connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "127.0.0.1", 8080);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "127.0.0.1", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);```. Changes happen in localhost UI but nothing in ```http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore ```. ```127.0.0.1:5000``` is still reading from main database.

Comment: Did you also update the condition: `hostname === "localhost"` in both places? Since react is client side, if you load 127.0.0.1 in your browser the localhost check will return false.

Aside from that, ensure you're starting the emulators with the same project ID as your connection info `demo-test` like so: `firebase emulators:start --project=demo-test`

Comment: ```firebase emulators:start --project=demo-test``` is what fixed it. Place that as an answer and i'll select as best answer.